# Trouble using fseek() in my function

Tags: c

I´m trying to use `fseek()` in a loop to print my structure but I can´t seem to find the problem here.

If I want to print the first element I get a signal error and the pointer `k` points to 0x1.

```
void drucke (struct anime *k, int max)
{
    int auswahl = 0;
    int grenze1, grenze2;

    printf("\n\nWillst du mehrere Elemente ausgeben (2) oder nur eins(1)?");
    scanf("%d",&auswahl);
    loescheTastaturpuffer();

    if (auswahl == 1)
    {
        printf("\nWelche Nummer moechtest du ausgeben? Maximalnummer ist %d:",max);
        scanf("%d",&grenze1);
        loescheTastaturpuffer();
        fp = fopen(filename,"rb");
        fseek(fp,(grenze1-1) * sizeof(struct anime),SEEK_SET);

        fread(&k,sizeof(struct anime),1,fp);
        printf("\nNummer des Animes : %d",k->animenr);
        printf("\nName des Animes  : %s",k->animename);
        printf("Season des Animes: %s",k->animeseason);
        printf("Start des Animes: %d",k->datumstart);

        fclose(fp);
    }
```

That's my function, and this is how I open it in my main.

```
drucke(&speicher[0], i);
```

`speicher` is from the same type as my structure.

This is how I write into the file.

```
void schreibe(struct anime *k,int max)
{
    int i;
    if ((fp = fopen (filename,"wb")) == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "\nDatei konnte nicht geöffnet werden");
    }

    for (i=0; i < max;i++)
    {
        fwrite(& *(k + sizeof(list)*i),sizeof(list),1,fp);
    }

    fclose(fp);
}
```

Comment: Is this an anime scraper in German?

Comment: Please format your text code properly.

Comment: @Kupiakos: What is an anime scrapper?

Comment: One obvious problem is that you do not check whether the call to `fopen()` succeeds before you use the result that it returned.  This can generate a segmentation fault and signal.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] (Minimales, vollständiges, überprüfbares (d.h. compilierbares - bis auf den Fehler und sowiet möglich, selbstverständlich), Beispiel).

Comment: @Olaf A program that downloads anime (Japanese cartoons) to local storage en masse. They're of dubious legality.

Comment: @Kupiakos: I will not discuss legality, but to me it looks more like some kind of database program. But maybe the socket part is yet to come.

Comment: Always check the returned values (not the parameters) for calls to fopen(), fseek(),  scanf(), and fread() to assure the operations were successful.

Comment: Note: if `loescheTastaturpuffer` uses something like `fflush(stdin)`: that is undefined behaviour according to the C standard.

Comment: the passed parameter 'k' is already a pointer, and fread() is expecting a pointer to the buffer, not a pointer to a pointer to the buffer.

Comment: Run the program in a debugger and check function results. Also enable compiler warnings and pay heed to them.

Comment: when calling 'fwrite()' the returned value should be compared against the third parameter to assure the operation was successful

Comment: Hmm... OP seems to have gone to bed, or that was some "fire and forget" question.

Comment: Have you run this in a debugger?  You need to narrow this down to the simplest reproducible cause/error before people will generally help you.

Comment: ok. I will try your solutions. I want to make a databse file that stores the animes that I watched.